# C# работа с бд в онлайн и оффлайн режиме

Tags: c#, mysql, база-данных

Есть бд на MySQL которая располагается на хостинге. Нужно реализовать возможность работать с базой локально когда отсудствует подключение к интернету.

- Как правильно организовать копирование бд с хостинга на локальную машину?
- Как отслеживать изменения в оффлайн режиме и регистрировать их в бд на сервере при подключении к интернету?

Comment: @Mike ну хоть что-то же должно быть, как это реализуют в остальных приложениях, кто-то должен знать

Comment: ну просто везде по разному. У оракла например для тяжелых случаев есть режим завершения "по телефону". Т.е. админины созваниваются и принимают решение какую транзакцию завершить, а какую нет :)

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял Вам необходимо настроить репликацию. Репликация это механизм позвзоляющий копировать данные с одной БД на другую. О ней вы можете почитать к [примеру здесь](https://ruhighload.com/post/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+MySQL+Master-Slave+%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E) или [здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/56702/).

В зависимости от настроек вы можете реплицировать всю базу данных, отдельную таблицу или ее часть. В случае необходимости двунаправленной репликации вы можете для обмена данными в кластере (master — master) установить два направления: master — slave и slave – master. Такая схема, в зависимости от проекта, у одних работает годами, у других сразу создает ряд проблем. Начиная с MySQL 5.1.18, возможность master — master поддерживается уже официально, включая multi-master репликации, в том числе и круговые. [Источник](https://www.tux.in.ua/articles/3586)